# Why Can't I get these divs to be the same height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get 2 divs to have the same vertical height in Bootstrap 3, but it's not working.  I'm using the display:table-layout on the parent, and display:table-cell + vertical-align:middle on the child.

```
.left {
    background-color:#bdc3c7;
    height:90px;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    ;
}
.right {
    background-color:aliceblue;
    height:90px;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.leftfont {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.rightfont {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This shows what it looks like:
http://jsfiddle.net/dqPzW/1/

Comment: Are you talking about the two "row" divs?

Comment: TidyUp is your friend. It's not helping at all that you have your CSS in there twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
display: table
```

should be

```
display: table-cell
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dqPzW/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `font-size: 1.5em;` in you class `.leftfont`.

He + the pading rules are oversizing your div.